# How can I create a link using the data source in Datatables Row Grouping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using Datatables 1.10 plug-in for Jquery with Row Grouping advanced initialisation: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html and I would like to add a link from a database to the grouped column, in the example the link would be **Edinburgh**, **London** etc.

Before I was using column.render: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render to add a link and it was working. As you can see in the code I am targeting column 1 **(working)** and would like to target column 0, the hidden column that is grouped **(not working)**.

*Column 0 is hidden and contains the group name.
Column 3 is hidden and contains the link.*

JS Code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var dataTable = $('#example').DataTable({
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"ajax":{
        url :"example.php", // json datasource
        type: "post",  // method  , by default get
            error: function(){  // error handling
              $(".example-error").html("");
              $("#example").append('<tbody class="example-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
              $("#example_processing").css("display","none");
            }
          },

          "columnDefs": [
          { "visible": false, "targets": [ 0, 3] },
          { "width": "50%", "targets": [ 1, 2 ] },
          { "orderable": false, "targets": [ 1, 2 ] },
          { "targets": 1,
          "data": null,
          "render": function ( data ) {
            return '<a href=//'+data[ 3 ]+' target="_blank">'+data[ 1 ]+'</a>';
          }}
          ],

          "order": [[ 0, 'asc' ]],
          "displayLength": 25,
          "drawCallback": function ( settings ) {
            var api = this.api();
            var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();
            var last = null;

            api.column(0, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
              if ( last !== group ) {
                $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                  '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5">'+group+'</td></tr>'
                  );

                last = group;
              }
            } );
          }
        } );
        } );
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You need to modify [`drawCallback`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) function as shown below:

```
api.rows({page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( data, i ) {
   var group = data[0];
   var groupLink = '<a href="' + data[3] + '">' + $('<div>').text(group).html() + '</a>';

   if ( last !== group ) {
      $(rows).eq( i ).before(
         '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5">'+group+'</td></tr>'
      );

      last = group;
   }
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1v0mzLb3/1/) for code and demonstration.

> **NOTES**

I also used [`orderFixed`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/orderFixed) so that table is always sorted by column containing group name (`2` in my example).

Comment: You sir, are a genius! Thank you!

Comment: This examples seems to be exactly what I need @Gyrocode.com... except that I need to replace the # with the data[3] as in the code above.  My datatable is using "ajax":{url:"myurl.json", "type": "POST", "dataSrc": "myname"}.  So I believe I may need to add the dataSrc to data[3]?  Could you help me with this?